# Why does my HTC Desire 610, running Android v4.4.2 and WiFi connected, falsely allege "your phone is up to date" and "no updates available"?

Tags: updates

While cleaning my attic, I unerathed an HTC Desire 610 from 2014. I hope to use it as a backup phone. I can't afford to buy a new phone, as COVID unemployed me.

As at today, the Latest release is Android 11. So why's my HTC Desire 610 fibbing, and not updating to Android 11? I connected it successfully to WiFi, which I checked by accessing the Internet.

[image]

Comment: Probably it means that the vendor has issued no further updates for that particular handset. Many vendors do that, and then you are stranded with an obsolete version when they stop supporting it. I guess you can update it to something more recent if you can root the device.

Comment: Not all Android devices get the current latest Android version, especially the older devices. This is because unlike OS for PC, there's no universal Android ROM that can be flashed on every device, so each vendor has to build each ROM for each device they want to support. Most vendors only provide at most 2-3 years updates of Android versions. The only alternative is looking for custom ROM (if it exists) for your device.

Comment: Also, according to [GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire_610-6160.php), the phone only gets Android 4.4.2 (no update) officially.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Upgrade my Android device to latest Android version](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226636/how-to-upgrade-a-galaxy-tab-a-model-sm-t550-to-the-latest-android)