# I want to update ASUS MeMO Pad 8 (vendor: au) to anything modern OS

Tags: adb, fastboot

I bought ASUS MeMO Pad 8 (AST21) from au, a vendor on KDDI CORPORATION, which seems to different from other ASUS MeMO Pad 8.

Then I terminated the device before I unlocked its SIM; so still locked.

At first its Android version used to be 4.4.2 (KitKat); I found and tried [this article reviewing upgrating to Lollipop using unofficial zip file.](https://ast21.appnote.info/archives/647) (official upgrading things seemed not to be available any more; or it might not be available in the first place.) It changed my tablet's model number to K015.

Then I thought if its OS could be replaced, or if it could be upgraded more.

How could I enable flashing to booting section, or whatever appropriate?

`fastboot flashing unlock` or other `flashing` commands showed me `FAILED (remote: 'unknown OEM command')`.

Both `adb devices` (works only when booted normally) and `fastboot devices` (works only on bootloader) recognize my tablet.

I am GNU/Linux user now; not Windows user.

Comment: How to unlock bootloader can be different for each device model. So general commands you find don't have to work. Some devices don't allow bootloader unlocking at all. But before you don't have a matching custom ROM you don't need to unlock your bootloader. As you phone is pretty old it is normal that ROM download links don't work anymore. If you consider rooting a phone later you have to download the ROMs while the phone is not too old. Please read also https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226636/2241