# Is it possible to upgrade One UI Core 5.1 to One UI 5.1 on unsupported devices?

Tags: samsung, samsung-one-ui

I have a Samsung Galaxy M12 device with One UI Core 5.1, but I want to use some features that are not available in One UI Core. Is there any way I can upgrade to the full version of One UI, and what problems might this potentially cause?

Comment: One UI Core is part of the system firmware and can not be upgraded without a firmware upgrade. Therefore your question is the same as [How to upgrade my Android device to latest Android version](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226636/224)