# Installing Android 12 (or 13, 14) on a Lenovo Tab M10 FHD Plus (2nd Gen, TB-X606X)

Tags: updates, lenovo, operating-system

Is there a way to install Android 12 / 13 / 14 on a Lenovo Tab M10 FHD Plus (2nd Gen, TB-X606X)? That is all I want to know if it is possible to do it, and how to do it then (currently running Android 9).

And whats the newest version of Android that can be installed there thats stable and not too slow?
Would my device get bricked when something untill i reflash it or would it be in that state forever?

Comment: The answer is still more or less the same as here: [How to upgrade my Android device to latest Android version](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226636/2241) If there is no custom ROM the only alternative would be a Android GSI image (assuming your tablet is Treble compatible), however I am not sure how usable a device with GSI image installed is.

Comment: This device is still being sold today with the same Android version so the short answer is no.